# How does the Random Number Generator work?

Tags: combinations, random, programming, permutation-cycles

I've always wondered that if computers or calculators for that matter work exactly the way we program them, then how is it possible for them to generate random numbers that are unbiased. How do they calculate combinations and permutations, if they use them?

Comment: You will find a detailed answer to your question in the wikipedia article [Random number generation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation).

Comment: This is two different questions: (1) How do computers generate random numbers and (2) How can random numbers be used to generate various random combinatorial objects. For (1) see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2056780